# How to set song as an alarm in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to set any song in my iPhone as an alarm tone. How will I access my songs and set it as an alarm?
And can I increase the time of alarm more than 40 secs? I mean i want to play full song as an alarm tone. Thanks

Comment: i think that's not not possible.

Comment: @hallie: But its a very common feature on a many mobile phones. Setting song as an alarm tone is not a very big deal. I hope there should be some solution .

Comment: do you think this question is related to application development?

Comment: @Suriya: I am developing an app in which I have to set an alarm and I want to play a song rather than any ring tone provided in the iPhone. In other words I want to customize the alarm feature of iPhone.

Comment: That can possible and you can play 5 min song as alarm ,me play song from webservice as alarm

Comment: @Harsh: All right So you are creating an alarm application. You can use AVAudioplayer for playing the songs

Comment: harsh that is possible and i done this i will send you link and code of that

Comment: @Suriya: I have that in my mind and I will use the Local Notification Feature of Apple to play the alarm but my main question is that "How can I set a song as an alram tone?" please give some sample code if u can

Comment: @GhostRider: Thanks for the code. But if u can please send me the link of this code that I will understand better and that will be very kind of u as I am working on Alarm feature first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[save the representativeItem from the collection returned to user info dictionary

when you want to play the song back, use MPMediaQuery to get the specific song to play.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008220

details on how to query for the stored song

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPropertyPredicate_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MPMediaPropertyPredicate/predicateWithValue:forProperty:

Apple Documentation for Querying data, plus examples

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString (@"Select any song from the list", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
[picker release];
```